# How to identify the source file which causes the Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a problem when trying to compile Swift 3.1 on Xcode 8.3.3
The Xcode said:

> :0: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
>   :0: error: compile command failed due to signal (use -v to
>   see invocation)

But I cannot figure out the swift file that cause the segmentation fault.

Logs Detail:

> CompileSwift normal x86_64
>       cd /Users/hainguyen/Workspace/Flo/FloUniversal/Flo
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift
>   -frontend -c -filelist /var/folders/cb/n_ccw95n7zs11l87f9w98s7h0000gn/T/sources-ca5acd
>   -target x86_64-apple-ios8.3 -enable-objc-interop -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.3.sdk
>   -I /Users/hainguyen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Flo-dvhxokbnekzqxkdydjtabfyrwxeb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F /Users/hainguyen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Flo-dvhxokbnekzqxkdydjtabfyrwxeb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F /Users/hainguyen/Workspace/Flo/FloUniversal/Flo/Flo/Platforms/ios/Frameworks
>   -enable-testing -g -module-cache-path /Users/hainguyen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -D
>   DEBUG -serialize-debugging-options -Xcc
>   -I/Users/hainguyen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Flo-dvhxokbnekzqxkdydjtabfyrwxeb/Build/Intermediates/Flo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flo.build/swift-overrides.hmap
>   -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/hainguyen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Flo-dvhxokbnekzqxkdydjtabfyrwxeb/Build/Intermediates/Flo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flo.build/Flo-generated-files.hmap
>   -Xcc -I/Users/hainguyen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Flo-dvhxokbnekzqxkdydjtabfyrwxeb/Build/Intermediates/Flo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flo.build/Flo-own-target-headers.hmap
>   -Xcc -I/Users/hainguyen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Flo-dvhxokbnekzqxkdydjtabfyrwxeb/Build/Intermediates/Flo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flo.build/Flo-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap
>   -Xcc -ivfsoverlay -Xcc /Users/hainguyen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Flo-dvhxokbnekzqxkdydjtabfyrwxeb/Build/Intermediates/Flo.build/all-product-headers.yaml
>   -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/hainguyen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Flo-dvhxokbnekzqxkdydjtabfyrwxeb/Build/Intermediates/Flo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flo.build/Flo-project-headers.hmap
>   -Xcc -I/Users/hainguyen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Flo-dvhxokbnekzqxkdydjtabfyrwxeb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include
>   -Xcc -I/Users/hainguyen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Flo-dvhxokbnekzqxkdydjtabfyrwxeb/Build/Intermediates/Flo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flo.build/DerivedSources/x86_64
>   -Xcc -I/Users/hainguyen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Flo-dvhxokbnekzqxkdydjtabfyrwxeb/Build/Intermediates/Flo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flo.build/DerivedSources
>   -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -Xcc -working-directory/Users/hainguyen/Workspace/Flo/FloUniversal/Flo -emit-module-doc-path /Users/hainguyen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Flo-dvhxokbnekzqxkdydjtabfyrwxeb/Build/Intermediates/Flo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flo.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Flo.swiftdoc
>   -serialize-diagnostics-path /Users/hainguyen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Flo-dvhxokbnekzqxkdydjtabfyrwxeb/Build/Intermediates/Flo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flo.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.dia
>   -import-objc-header /Users/hainguyen/Workspace/Flo/FloUniversal/Flo/Flo/Platforms/ios/Application/Flo-Bridging-Header.h
>   -O -module-name Flo -emit-module-path /Users/hainguyen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Flo-dvhxokbnekzqxkdydjtabfyrwxeb/Build/Intermediates/Flo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flo.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Flo.swiftmodule
>   -emit-objc-header-path /Users/hainguyen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Flo-dvhxokbnekzqxkdydjtabfyrwxeb/Build/Intermediates/Flo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flo.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Flo-Swift.h
>   -emit-dependencies-path /Users/hainguyen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Flo-dvhxokbnekzqxkdydjtabfyrwxeb/Build/Intermediates/Flo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flo.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.d
>   -num-threads 4 -output-filelist /var/folders/cb/n_ccw95n7zs11l87f9w98s7h0000gn/T/outputs-11dbac
>
> 0  swift                    0x000000010412b4f7
>   PrintStackTraceSignalHandler(void*) + 39 1  swift
>   0x000000010412a9a6 SignalHandler(int) + 646 2 
>   libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff9a5b5b3a _sigtramp + 26 3 
>   libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff5ed2a0c8 _sigtramp + 3296150952 4 
>   swift                    0x0000000101b80ba2
>   swift::Lowering::TypeConverter::getFunctionInterfaceTypeWithCaptures(swift::CanTypeWrapper,
>   swift::AnyFunctionRef) + 242 5  swift
>   0x0000000101b30f1d
>   swift::Lowering::TypeConverter::getConstantInfo(swift::SILDeclRef) +
>   157 6  swift                    0x0000000101b52af0
>   swift::SILModule::getOrCreateFunction(swift::SILLocation,
>   swift::SILDeclRef, swift::ForDefinition_t) + 96 7  swift
>   0x00000001017284c0
>   swift::Lowering::SILGenModule::getFunction(swift::SILDeclRef,
>   swift::ForDefinition_t) + 304 8  swift
>   0x00000001017ed93c
>   swift::Lowering::SILGenModule::emitVTableMethod(swift::SILDeclRef,
>   swift::SILDeclRef, swift::SILLinkage&) + 60 9  swift
>   0x00000001017efc6c (anonymous
>   namespace)::SILGenVTable::addEntry(swift::SILDeclRef) + 876 10 swift
>   0x00000001017ef5fa swift::ASTVisitor<(anonymous
>   namespace)::SILGenVTable, void, void, void, void, void,
>   void>::visit(swift::Decl*) + 778 11 swift
>   0x00000001017eeca3 (anonymous namespace)::SILGenType::emitType() + 371
>   12 swift                    0x00000001017eeacd
>   swift::Lowering::SILGenModule::visitNominalTypeDecl(swift::NominalTypeDecl*)
>   + 29 13 swift                    0x0000000101736ecb swift::Lowering::SILGenModule::emitSourceFile(swift::SourceFile*,
>   unsigned int) + 1483 14 swift                    0x0000000101738af2
>   swift::SILModule::constructSIL(swift::ModuleDecl*, swift::SILOptions&,
>   swift::FileUnit*, llvm::Optional, bool, bool) + 1666 15
>   swift                    0x0000000100f49561
>   swift::performFrontend(llvm::ArrayRef, char const*,
>   void*, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 42353 16 swift
>   0x0000000100ef8d6c main + 9052 17 libdyld.dylib
>   0x00007fff9a3a6235 start + 1 18 libdyld.dylib
>   0x0000000000000046 start + 1707449874 Stack dump:
>   0.    Program arguments: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift
>   -frontend -c -filelist /var/folders/cb/n_ccw95n7zs11l87f9w98s7h0000gn/T/sources-ca5acd
>   -target x86_64-apple-ios8.3 -enable-objc-interop -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.3.sdk
>   -I /Users/hainguyen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Flo-dvhxokbnekzqxkdydjtabfyrwxeb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F /Users/hainguyen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Flo-dvhxokbnekzqxkdydjtabfyrwxeb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F /Users/hainguyen/Workspace/Flo/FloUniversal/Flo/Flo/Platforms/ios/Frameworks
>   -enable-testing -g -module-cache-path /Users/hainguyen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -D
>   DEBUG -serialize-debugging-options -Xcc
>   -I/Users/hainguyen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Flo-dvhxokbnekzqxkdydjtabfyrwxeb/Build/Intermediates/Flo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flo.build/swift-overrides.hmap
>   -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/hainguyen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Flo-dvhxokbnekzqxkdydjtabfyrwxeb/Build/Intermediates/Flo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flo.build/Flo-generated-files.hmap
>   -Xcc -I/Users/hainguyen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Flo-dvhxokbnekzqxkdydjtabfyrwxeb/Build/Intermediates/Flo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flo.build/Flo-own-target-headers.hmap
>   -Xcc -I/Users/hainguyen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Flo-dvhxokbnekzqxkdydjtabfyrwxeb/Build/Intermediates/Flo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flo.build/Flo-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap
>   -Xcc -ivfsoverlay -Xcc /Users/hainguyen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Flo-dvhxokbnekzqxkdydjtabfyrwxeb/Build/Intermediates/Flo.build/all-product-headers.yaml
>   -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/hainguyen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Flo-dvhxokbnekzqxkdydjtabfyrwxeb/Build/Intermediates/Flo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flo.build/Flo-project-headers.hmap
>   -Xcc -I/Users/hainguyen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Flo-dvhxokbnekzqxkdydjtabfyrwxeb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include
>   -Xcc -I/Users/hainguyen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Flo-dvhxokbnekzqxkdydjtabfyrwxeb/Build/Intermediates/Flo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flo.build/DerivedSources/x86_64
>   -Xcc -I/Users/hainguyen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Flo-dvhxokbnekzqxkdydjtabfyrwxeb/Build/Intermediates/Flo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flo.build/DerivedSources
>   -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -Xcc -working-directory/Users/hainguyen/Workspace/Flo/FloUniversal/Flo -emit-module-doc-path /Users/hainguyen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Flo-dvhxokbnekzqxkdydjtabfyrwxeb/Build/Intermediates/Flo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flo.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Flo.swiftdoc
>   -serialize-diagnostics-path /Users/hainguyen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Flo-dvhxokbnekzqxkdydjtabfyrwxeb/Build/Intermediates/Flo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flo.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.dia
>   -import-objc-header /Users/hainguyen/Workspace/Flo/FloUniversal/Flo/Flo/Platforms/ios/Application/Flo-Bridging-Header.h
>   -O -module-name Flo -emit-module-path /Users/hainguyen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Flo-dvhxokbnekzqxkdydjtabfyrwxeb/Build/Intermediates/Flo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flo.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Flo.swiftmodule
>   -emit-objc-header-path /Users/hainguyen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Flo-dvhxokbnekzqxkdydjtabfyrwxeb/Build/Intermediates/Flo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flo.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Flo-Swift.h
>   -emit-dependencies-path /Users/hainguyen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Flo-dvhxokbnekzqxkdydjtabfyrwxeb/Build/Intermediates/Flo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flo.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.d
>   -num-threads 4 -output-filelist /var/folders/cb/n_ccw95n7zs11l87f9w98s7h0000gn/T/outputs-11dbac

Answer (score 0):

The cause of `Segmentation fault: 11` is the complex expression or function which you have written in your `.swift` file. You can debug the issue just by checking out the line number mentioned in the error, e.g.:

> swift::Lowering::TypeConverter::getFunctionInterfaceTypeWithCaptures(swift::CanTypeWrapper,
>   swift::AnyFunctionRef) + 242 5 swift

If you still cannot debug the issue, pls put the demo code or above mentioned files online and I will help you out.

Comment: I have added full Xcode Error Logs, could you please give me a help ?
Thanks Sohil R. Memon !

Comment: @haithngn I want to see coding. It's not going to help me in any way.

Comment: the source code is too big, too many files :(
Can we analyze the error log ?

Comment: @haithngn Sorry I can't because I need to see the coding to identify the issue. To cut it down, can you pls send me that part where you have written complex conversion or something like a big logic

Comment: I want to send you the my coding !
Can I have your email address Sohil R. Memon ?
Or could you please send message to haithngn@gmail.com

Comment: @haithngn Email sent.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling Swift Compiler Optimization for Release
to be more specific: In your target > Build Settings > Optimization Level > Release > No optimization

Answer (score -1):

No way to identify the segmentation fault swift file from error log.

I tried remove some swift files in the source codes and re-import them then now Segmentation fault error are now disappear.

I don't know why but resolved.

Thanks Sohil R. Memon for your time.